# How to run SQL Agent Job based on specific days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have 2 SQL Agent Jobs as below

- Job 1: End of Day (EOD) Job
- Job 2: End of Month (EOM) Job

The schedule are below:

- For EOD job, it should run on every Tues, Wed, Thurs, Fri and Sun (1
  am).
- For EOM job, it should run on every 1st day of the month.

The tricky part is:

1. EOD job shouldn't run on 1st day of the month (took over by EOM job).
2. If the end of month date fall on Friday (i.e. 31 Mar 2017), then

   - EOM job should run on 2nd day of the month (Sunday - 2 Apr 2017).
   - EOD should not run on Sunday - 2 Apr 2017.
3. If the end of month date fall on Sunday (i.e. 30 Apr 2017), then

   - EOM job should run on Sunday - 30 Apr 2017.
   - EOD should not run on Sunday - 30 Apr 2017.

Answer (score 1):

you can always simply create a daily job in SQL Agent and write the control logic on if the job decides to execute inside a stored proc

Comment: Just wondering, is it possible to perform the scheduling in the SQL Agent Job itself instead of using stored proc?

Comment: what you see is what you get in the interface through SSMS, if you want anything more complex, you have to put the logic either in t-sql or powershell